# How do I fix a "/tmp is not ready or mounted" Error?

Tags: 12.04, hard-drive, startup, ssd, spotify

I run ubuntu 12.04 LTS on a Lenovo ideapad netbook S10. I Been getting this error a lot, and then I did a fresh install. I had ubuntu only a month now, but the error hadn't started till yesterday morning, then I did a fresh install. This morning I got the same error again. I opened the netbook and the Motherboard, Hard drive, and SSD drive are all properly connected. and did a smart test and my HDD is healthy. I noticed this only started up after I installed the program spotify. Could this be the issue? When I had it in windows vista it gave the other machine a BSOD on launch.

update: Did another fresh install and no error on launches. (never installed spotify.) Both machines experienced this error.

Comment: Might be related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mountall/+bug/1091792

Comment: Can you explain this to me in a less technical way? I am really new to Ubuntu and linux in general.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the permissions in the /tmp directory? Maybe

```
ls -la /tmp
```

can help you by displaying the owners and files in /tmp. Let us know!

Comment: @rinzwind [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/50904504/Screenshot%20from%202013-06-28%2016%3A26%3A40.png) This is what I keep getting.